# How did people started following same dates around the world?

Tags: humans

When there was no common culture and communication between the people around the world in olden days, how did they all come to a understanding of using same dates and days.

Comment: How old are "olden days"? This is important, because without a clear context it's hard to understand what you mean by "same dates". Up to the second half of the 19th century (that's less than 200 years ago) there were quite a few different calendar date systems in use; and multiple calendar systems are *still* in use for specific purposes. Consider for example that the [Great Socialist October Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/October_Revolution) actually took place in what we call *November* 1917; that is, 100 years ago, what the Russians called 25 October was 7 November in the west.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I would also recommend you clarify your question as to what exactly you mean by "dates." There's a lot of components in dates, and not all of them were invented at teh same time and for the same reasons.

Comment: This seems more like a history question than worldbuilding.

Comment: @AlexP SF and nonfiction author Isaac Asimov used to say he wasn't sure when his birthday was, because he was born in Russia,under the Julian calendar, and had never been sure whether the birthday he celebrated as a child had been "corrected" for the calendar change or not -- and the difference by then was, as noted in your comment, close to two weeks.

Comment: In many cases, folks did NOT come to an understanding. Western and Eastern christian churches still use different calendars today. China and some Arab countries use *two* calendars side-by-side, each for a different purpose.

Comment: Japan uses its own calendar, in which this is year 1 of the Reiwa era.  Even in the US (at least in the west), it's common to see cornerstones of public buildings that have A.L. dates derived from Masonic/Christian mythology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_Lucis

Answer (score 2):

At first, people didn't follow the same calendars at all. Many cultures had different calendars, although it was trivial for many of them to discover that 365 and 1/4 days was a good approximation of the number of days in a year.

But most cultures had no unified conception of specific dates, with the one exception being that many cultures had some kind of celebrations around the [Summer Solstice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_solstice) (longest day of the year), [Winter Solstice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winter_solstice) (shortest day of the year), and the [Spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/March_equinox#Culture) and [Fall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/September_equinox#Culture) Equinoxes (the two days of the year when you have equal length of day and night).

Rome unified much of the world and when inventing the [Julian Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar#Context_of_the_reform), its influence caused many other parts of the world to adapt this.  The Julian Calendar was later replaced by the Gregorian Calendar and so forth.

[Full history of calendars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_calendars#Christian_Europe).

Answer (score 2):

The standard method was "Who is the biggest guy in the neighbourhood who is going to force us to use their calendar?" or "Who is the biggest guy in the neighbourhood whose calendar we have to use in order to get any trading done with them?" Which is pretty much the same thing.

Thus the initial use of the Egyptian and Sumerian calendars, with the Sumerian Calendar leading to the Babylonian Calendar, which led to descendants such as the Jewish and Persian calendars. The Greeks developed theirs, which led to both the Roman and Hindu calendars, and so on. The Roman calendar became the standard for later Europeans countries, and they proceeded to take it with them when they went off to trade and grab as much as they could around the world.

As to how they communicated, it simply was the responsibility of the people who needed to know, such as traders and ambassadors, to figure out the equivalents. Someone living in Thebes didn't need to know that the third day of the week of the second month of the third year of the reign of the current pharaoh was called something different in Ur, nor would they have cared.

Comment: The Roman calendar never had any relationship with the Greek calendar. In fact it is not at all straightforward to convert ancient Greek dates into Roman dates. (And anyway, before the reforms of Julius Caesar the Roman calendar was a horrible mess. Anecdote: when Caesar [crossed the Adriatic in pursuit of Pompey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Pharsalus), Pompey's admirals thought that it was *winter*, because that's what the calendar said, and thus the crossing would be too dangerous. Caesar had better astronomers and knew it was *spring*, so the risk was acceptable.)